# How do I satisfy a requirement to scan text files for malware?

Tags: malware

We have a requirement (on our **closed** network) to scan any file(s) introduced on the system for content that will do something "bad". (Bad is not the exact wording, just the intent.)

This started when I wanted to bring in Puppet files, which are text only, non-executables. Ruby interprets the text file and then ruby executes some commands. So, Puppet files are text only & not executable.

This could apply to any script file: perl, python, bash, etc.

Right now, we have to do a *line-by-line* code review of everything. Uggh.

My questions:
A. How do I satisfy this "requirement" in a reasonable way -- even if it is just "checking a box."
B. If it is not reasonably satisfyable, what are some awesome words to send to my Information Security folks to explain why this is unnecessary/ridiculous/waste of time, etc?

I will accept personal opinions or speculations, as long as they are marked as such.

Comment: It is not the file that might have malware but the puppet process that runs the text file might do something bad. So I think your Security people are correct. cf bash files they are text but could include `rm -rf `

Comment: Yet, `rm -rf` cannot be detected as a malware nor even harmful: the system is doing exactly what you command it to do, and there's no judging whether `rm -rf` is useful or harmful. Unless it has `/` as its target.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. That is EXACTLY the problem. Somehow, I have to say that it has been "scanned" for unwanted actions.  
Maybe rm -rf is OK, maybe it isn't. 
So, what is a _reasonable_ approach?

Comment: You’re looking for a way to call out something malicious, when in a controlled environment it might be easier to apply a model where it is ok to run as long as it came from a trusted source. I’m not sure how that fits into the puppet model, but you might be able to use GPG signatures in git commits or on a file level if no source control context is available. This is the basis for the security behind most software distribution methods, with malware detection being a layer on top to protect users from themselves.

Comment: I like the way you think, @nbering. The I.S. folks say that a "bad actor" could upload malicious code, and update the hash check, which would fool me into thinking it was OK.
Really, what I have to do is find a reasonable way to satisfy the requirement -- or -- prove that there is no way to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: The trick with code signing is that the public key needs to be distributed separately and preferably in advance of the code to be distributed. That’s part of what makes it a stronger check than just a hash.

Comment: Side note: Remember that _all_ files on a computer are binary-based, even if a small subset are usually trivially considered "text".  Remember that malicious "binary" files - like images - were so because of bugs in implementations of decoders, not because the file itself was inherently executable.  It's _possible_ (although, especially at this late date, difficult to impossible) to create such a malicious text file.

Comment: The question really is: How do I satisfy the requirement in a reasonable & repeatable way. 
And, yes, I know it's a bit ridiculous. I still need to do it, even if it is "just checking off a box"

Comment: Rephrased the question. I'm in a bit of a bind here. All ideas welcome!